# android webview http site intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-security

android 9.0 pie
compileSdkVersion 26
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 28

Hi,
I'm trying to publish my android app
but I've got a problem

android 9.0 doesn't support http 
so, I change a code like this

```
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
```

and a published.. but i got this mail

**Intent Scheme Hijacking
Your app(s) are using a WebView that is vulnerable to Intent scheme hijacking.
To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of your app to the Play Console and check back after five hours to make sure the warning is gone.**

here is my code
AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="{value}"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Activity.java

```
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            if (url.substring(0, 6).equals("intent"))
            {
                LoadEduManager(url);
            }
            else
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }

public void LoadEduManager(String url)
    {
        boolean flag = true;
        try
        {
            PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

            String appPkg = "com.cdn.";
            PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(appPkg, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            flag = false;
        }

        if (flag)
        {
            try 
            {
                Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (URISyntaxException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity_Notice.this)
            .setTitle("")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage("")
            .setPositiveButton("확     인", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {               
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(""));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            })
            .show();
        }
    }
```

I really don't know how to I solve this problem
google's Answer
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9101196?hl=en

I try this case
if i connect the http site then, doesn't show error page
but, I get a Jquery error. If i enter using a browser, it comes out normally in This case

```
<application usesCleartextTraffic=false networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

network_security_config

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">yeosj.com</domain>

    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Google recommends launching a browser rather than webview(embedded browser). Any security-related information could easily be intercepted in the webview. For your reference, google started blocking oath authentication via webview https://auth0.com/blog/google-blocks-oauth-requests-from-embedded-browsers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `network_security_config` file like this one and check

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: thanks reply 
network-security-config code doesn't show security error
but, I can't recieve data from server... : ( 
error is jqeury not defined error 
in fact, call jqeury successfully in code ..

Answer (score 0):

change you sdk version to

```
compileSdkVersion 29
 minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 29
```

Comment: thanks reply

I change a code and publish
but i got this error : 
Device deprecation
warning :
Deactivating this APK will reduce the number of device types for which you can install new apps.
Help :
If you inadvertently make changes, please keep this APK in the new version or check if the new APK supports all currently supported devices.

Comment: did you change  versionCode 1
       and  versionName "1.0"

Comment: @sahabeliy 
i change a versionCode 28 and versionName "2.8"
but pops above error

I think the sdk version has changed and the target devices have shrunk, so I lowered the MinSDKVersion to 14 again and are trying to release it.